# Password attempts in JFrame connected to SQL

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc

I created a JFrame log-in. It is connected to sql. The problem that I encounter is, if I run this and I input a wrong credential, else statement will execute 3 times.
This is my code:

```
String username = txtUsername.getText();
String password = txtPassword.getText();
String sql = "select * from users where username ='"+username+"' and password='"+password+"'";
ResultSet res = st.executeQuery(sql);

for (int i=0; i<3;i++){
    if (res.next()){
        dispose();
        up.show(); 
    }
    else{
        txtUsername.setText("");
        txtPassword.setText("");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Incorect inputs "+ i+ " attempts left");
    }
}
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, your idea is whenever the user inputs incorrect username/password, the textboxes will be clear to let user input again, 3 times maximum, right?

Comment: yes that is the idea

Comment: Then I recommend to remove the `for` loop, initialize a counter (starting at 0) instead. Whenever credential is wrong, the counter is increased until it reach the maximum attempting values

Comment: This problem could be sorted out in a command line app without a GUI, so do that and leave the `JFrame` tag out of it. Use a `PreparedStatement` - general advice, not relevant to the actual problem here. The solution to the problem at hand is to find a loop structure that will not repeat 3 times on error, or how to break out of the loop on error.